# Would it be possible to reverse engineer the wooting 60he keyboard to create a new pcb?

Tags: firmware-analysis, pcb

Would it be possible to build a pcb that is essentially a copy of the wooting Hall effect pcbs but with different layouts? (Ie: 65% or 75% layouts)

Would it be possible to transfer the firmware from the wooting pcb to another pcb so it is recognized by the software?

Comment: Recognized by what software? Firmware is software. It depends on the controller so you need the same one at minimum.

Comment: Wooting has their “wootility”software. I’d like for the software to recognize the new pcb as their full-size keyboard and just program keys to match the pcb layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source - reverse engineering isn't required because you can just look at it directly. https://github.com/WootingKb/